# Getting error on create table with foreign key constraint (Cascade)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table employee
(
  eid int primary key,
  ename varchar(50),
  cid int,
  sid int,
  constraint fk_hello1 foreign key(cid) references country(cid)on delete 
  cascade on update cascade,         
  constraint fk_hello2 foreign key(sid) references state(sid) on delete
  cascade on update cascade,
)
```

I have been trying to apply this code but am constantly getting the error msg.........

```
ERROR MESSAGE
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_hello2' on table 'employee' may 
cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: Delete the records from employee table.

Comment: @BGS there are no records in the employee table, i m creating the table.

Comment: Well - it seems you have multiple cascade paths as per the error description - you properly have between country and state or similar

Comment: Is there any FK relation between `country` and `state` tables/

Comment: Could u check State table values whether sid is primary key or not..?

Comment: @Allan, what does that mean? I want employee table(child table) to be related to city and state table(parent tables) so that if i make changes in either one of them, they get automatically changed in the other place and also if i wanna delete.

Comment: @shree.pat18, yes there is a FK relation between country and state too. state contains cid(countryID)

Comment: @androidrill Why you want reference [State] from [employee] ? [country] already reference [State]... Is State from country has a different meaning then state in employee ?

Comment: @Alexi Semidotsky, Show me the right way to approach this problem. I have 3 tables country(cid, name) state(sid,cid,sname) employee(eid,ename,cid,sid). How shud i make a relation between all the three??

Comment: @androidrill I posted schema in my answer in section 'Correct solution'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `on update cascade` when you have cycle references in you relations in database structure:

[image]

Only `NO ACTION` allowed (see you error `Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION`)

Is State from country has a different meaning then state in employee ?

### Correct solution:

[image]

and table [Employee] must have one foreign key on multiple columns - FK(CID, SID)

Comment: In that case, i must refer to only country(cid) via my employee table? or else how can i approach the problem??

Comment: You must refer to only state table (see schema above)

Comment: The illustration is beautiful and explanatory but can you actually put the schema into code so that i can understand how the above can be accomplished. The concept of 1FK for 2 fields is not what i know of. So plz explain.

Comment: First table *States* must have *primary key on columns (Cid, Sid)* and then you must declare your foreign key constraint as `CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_States] FOREIGN KEY([Cid], [Sid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State] ([Cid], [Sid])`

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to answer me but i still have another table  i.e. "country" having fields(cid(PK),cnames) which needs to be connected to "states" as well as "employees" tables.

Comment: I got your point and have also checked it through. Thanks a ton for helping me through this problem. plz refer some book or stuff that could help me in database architecture.

Comment: `use TestCascade
go

create table states
(
stid int primary key,
sname varchar(50),
)

create table country
(
cid int primary key,
cname varchar(50), 
)

create table employee
(
cid int,
stid int,
eid int primary key,
ename varchar(50),

CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_States] FOREIGN KEY(stid) REFERENCES States (stid) on delete cascade on update cascade,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_country] FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES country (cid) on delete cascade on update cascade,`

Comment: Happy to help! Best database-design book [Designing Effective Database Systems (Rebecca M. Riordan)](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/database-design/0321290933).
Also one of the best resources http://www.sqlservercentral.com/